# unix: using sed to replace filepaths with special characters

Tags: unix, replace, sed, filepath

I am trying to automate some scripts and need to change the paths of files one of the scripts reads to do the automation.

Because these paths have special characters, I am hitting a wall.
I have tried escaping the special characters but obviously I am doing sth wrong...

Here is what I have:

```
newpath="/media/g1/Enzymes@Work/MARENOSTRUM/PATHWAYS/COP/test1_A/"
sed -e "s/THISISTHEPATHTOTHEDIRECTORY/${newpath}/g" sampleTrajs.py
```

which gives me the expected error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Just use another sed separator: `sed -e "s|...|$newpath|g" file`. That is, use something that is not contained in the string you are changing. Otherwise, sed sees so many separators.

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly fine. did not know sed can work with other separators :P